# Prove that $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \ln\left(|f(x)|\right) + C$.

Tags: integration, solution-verification, absolute-value

I need to prove that
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \ln\left(|f(x)|\right) + C.$$ Working in $\mathbb{R}$.

My development was:

Deriving the RHS:
$$
{ \frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(|f(x)|\right) = \frac{1}{|f(x)|} \cdot \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|} \cdot f'(x) = \frac{f(x)f'(x)}{f^2(x)} =\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} }
$$
and therefore
$${ \ln\left(|f(x)|\right)} \ \ \ \text{ is the primitive of } \ \ {\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}.
$$

First, i need to check if my solution is correct. On the other hand, i want to know if there are other reasons(different of the common argument that says that logarithm take positive values) to take $\ln(|f(x)|) + C$ as the primitive instead of $\ln(f(x)) + C.$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In derivative line in last fraction denominator should be $f$, not $f^2$.

Comment: Note that you need to assume $f \neq 0$ on the region of integration.

Comment: @zkutch the last fraction is not $f^2$, so... ?

Comment: @AmorFati well, but what do you mean by region of integration?

Comment: @Eduardo Sebastián C. It was there when I wrote my comment. You can see edit history.  After you read this I can delete my comments.